# Chrome Audio Events does not works

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Here i have a piece of code for loading, playing and ending of audio file.The code have 2 html5 events. the code works fine for Firefox and IE but no audio event works on chrome. I am using chrome 28.0. Please help me about it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Put the link for any mp3 file in variable 'audiofile' to test the code
    var audiofile = "http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.mp3";

    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = audiofile;

    audio.oncanplay = function (){
        audio.play();
    }

    audio.onended = function(){
        alert('Playing Done');
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could hear audio in Chrome (v34).

Comment: Meaning my chrome have some problem. Thanks for help dear. I check it after installing new chrome.